# Simpler way to add code blocks?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

There has got to be a better way of adding code blocks than adding 4 spaces to EACH line. I have seen `<pre><code>` tags before, but they don't work when using `#include <someheader>`. Have I missed something?

Comment: *"Have I missed something?"* Er...the `{}` button?

Comment: Indeed I have. I've missed it for 10+ months now.

Comment: Shameless plug: http://stackapps.com/questions/3247/better-handling-of-indentation-and-the-tab-key-when-editing-posts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the <kbd>{ }</kbd> button - highlight the lines of code you want to turn into a code block, and hit the button.

[image]

```
Here is code on line one
Here is code on line two
```

There is also a <kbd>?</kbd> button at the top right of the textbox, you can click on that for more formatting help.

Comment: I honestly I have never seen this. Is this new?

Comment: @Drise definitely not.

Comment: @Drise See [my comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139748/linking-to-a-specific-answer-for-a-stack-overflow-question#comment394087_139748) on the question immediately preceding yours. Admittedly long ago it was called the `0101010101010101010101` button. But that was harder to type.

Comment: Also, select the whole block and press Ctrl+K (on Windows)